# On mouse hover list did not display

Tags: html, css-selectors

I have following html dynamically generated. My goal is to display dropdown list with the links in tag #level2, when mouse is over to corresponding parent li tag.

```
<div id="level1" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
    <li id="0" style="height: 30px; min-width: 190px; list-style: outside none none; border: 1px solid rgb(125, 153, 202); text-align: left; padding: 5%; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 2%; border-radius: 1px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(96, 96, 96);"> o Operating System ▸</li>
        <div id="level2" style="display: none; position: absolute; min-width: 160px;">
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Introduction </a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Synchronization</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Memory & Cache management</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">File system</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Storage management</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Management of process and threads</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Deadlock</a>
        </div>
    <li id="1" style="height: 30px; min-width: 190px; list-style: outside none none; border: 1px solid rgb(125, 153, 202); text-align: left; padding: 5%; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 2%; border-radius: 1px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(96, 96, 96);"> o Data Structures ▸</li>
        <div id="level2" style="display: none; position: absolute; min-width: 160px;">
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Basics</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Singly Linked List</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Doubly Linked list</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Trees</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Hash</a>
            <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 12px 16px; color: blue;">Graphs</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

To achieve this goal, i used following rules in a function to dynamically generate css, but it is not helping me.

```
element = "#level1";
$(element).css("position", "relative");
$(element).css("display", "inline-block");

for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    element = "#level1 li#" + i + ":hover > #level2";
    $(element).css("display", "block");
}

element = "#level1 #level2";
$(element).css("display", "none");
$(element).css("position", "absolute");
$(element).css("backgroud-color", "#f9f9f9");
$(element).css("min-width", "160px");

element = "#level1 #level2 a";
$(element).css("display", "block");
$(element).css("padding", "12px 16px");
$(element).css("color", "blue");

element = "#level1 #level2 a:hover";
$(element).css("background-color", "#606060");
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: **ID should be unique** for every element (`#level2`). So, use class instead. Also, you can achieve your goal with only CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was creating collapsable menu using dynamic input,  i have inserted a hierarchy of level0, level1, level2, to distinguish between the layers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure CSS example. I used external CSS to make it more managable.
Also, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sven_Knockaert/0ve1g0h9/).

**HTML:** (made your #level1 an `<ul>`, give your `<div>`'s a class, removed inline CSS)

```
<ul>
  <li> o Operating System ▸
    <div class="hidden-div">
      <a href="#">Introduction </a>
      <a href="#">Synchronization</a>
      <a href="#">Memory &amp; Cache management</a>
      <a href="#">File system</a>
      <a href="#">Storage management</a>
      <a href="#">Management of process and threads</a>
      <a href="#">Deadlock</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li> o Data Structures ▸
    <div class="hidden-div">
      <a href="#">Basics</a>
      <a href="#">Singly Linked List</a>
      <a href="#">Doubly Linked list</a>
      <a href="#">Trees</a>
      <a href="#">Hash</a>
      <a href="#">Graphs</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:** (a few minor things were changed, style as desired)

```
li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  border: 1px solid rgb(125, 153, 202);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
}

.hidden-div {
  margin-top: 26px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hidden-div a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  color: blue;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

li:hover .hidden-div {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sven,
although i resolved it in other way. i was doing a mistake, I should enclose <div id=level2> in li tag above it.